# Is there a word for exactly one hour starting on the hour?

Tags: word-choice

The period 10:00 to 11:00 is a complete hour. So is the period 10:08 to 11:08.

Yet the first, 10:00 to 11:00 is somehow special in that it covers the exact clock hour of 10.

Is there a word or shorter phrase for this? One that I could use in a sentence such as "Only [fully complete clock hours] count towards your hours worked." with the word replacing the bracketed phrase.

Comment: The idiomatic way of referring to exactly 10:00, 11:00, etc. is [*on the hour*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+hour). It doesn't fit your sentence structure though, and I'm not sure there's something that does. You might have to reword.

Comment: I don't know about a special word, but you could say, "Only full hours starting **on the hour** would count toward your hours worked." Another more informal expression is "at the top of the hour."

Comment: Hm, actually that might be 61 minutes, not 60.  Is a week Monday through Sunday, or Monday through Monday?  If it’s Monday through Sunday, then Monday through Monday must be a week and a day, and 10:00–11:00 looks a bit like an hour and a minute. Depends. A TV program that runs from 10:00–10:59 is an hour long so that the one beginning at 11:00 can start on time.

Comment: The title is incorrect. A *clock hour* is a duration of 60 minutes (by the clock), as opposed to say, a *class hour* of 50 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special word or phrase for it. An hour is any 60 minute period.

I'd rewrite your sentence based on J.R.'s suggestion:

> Only full hours starting on the hour count towards your hours worked.

Comment: This is not a one-word or a (standard/ suggested) set phrase or even a neologism. Counts as a comment. Not that Hugo doesn't know it perfectly well.

Comment: @Kris: I am saying there isn't one word for this or even a 
set phrase. I don't think inventing a neologism would help clearly communicate the concept. As an alternative, I offered a sentence in what I hope is plain enough English to be unambiguously understood.